# python : bind function to button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

this is my python code GUI generated from PAGE 4.6.

I want to create a function which will change the textbox value in real time example

```
tbCapturedImage.set("test 1").
```

take a look at

```
self.btnCapture.bind('<Button-1>', self.Capture_a)
```

but it cant seems to change the value of the textbox.

```
 self.tbCapturedImage = Text(self.TLabelframe1)
        self.tbCapturedImage.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.65, relheight=0.33
                , relwidth=0.93)
        self.tbCapturedImage.configure(background="white")
        self.tbCapturedImage.configure(font="TkTextFont")
        self.tbCapturedImage.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        self.tbCapturedImage.configure(width=206)
        self.tbCapturedImage.configure(wrap=WORD)


            self.btnCapture = Button(master)
            self.btnCapture.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.92, height=45, width=982)
            self.btnCapture.configure(activebackground="#d9d9d9")
            self.btnCapture.configure(disabledforeground="#a7a4a7")
            self.btnCapture.configure(font=font11)
            self.btnCapture.configure(text='''Capture Image''')
            self.btnCapture.bind('<Button-1>', self.Capture_a)

            self.Labelframe1 = LabelFrame(master)
            self.Labelframe1.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.48, relheight=0.43
                    , relwidth=0.74)
            self.Labelframe1.configure(relief=GROOVE)
            self.Labelframe1.configure(text='''Color Detection''')
            self.Labelframe1.configure(width=740)        
            self.Labelframe2 = LabelFrame(master)
            self.Labelframe2.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.05, relheight=0.43
                    , relwidth=0.35)
            self.Labelframe2.configure(relief=GROOVE)
            self.Labelframe2.configure(text='''Perspective Transformation''')
            self.Labelframe2.configure(width=350)        
            self.Labelframe3 = LabelFrame(master)
            self.Labelframe3.place(relx=0.61, rely=0.05, relheight=0.43
                    , relwidth=0.38)
            self.Labelframe3.configure(relief=GROOVE)
            self.Labelframe3.configure(text='''Haar-Like Detection''')
            self.Labelframe3.configure(width=380)                
        def Capture():
            tbCapture.Set("test")            
        def Capture_a(self,event):
            self.Capture()   

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        vp_start_gui()
```

Comment: If this is your code, it should give an error on line `self.Capture()`. Something like `Capture takes 0 arguments but 1 given.` Have you checked your console to see if there are any error messages?

Comment: Also, even though I can guess, can you please fix the indentation?

Comment: btw: instead `bind` you can use `Button(..., command=function_name)`

Comment: in method `Capture()` use `self.tbCapture` instead of `tbCapture` and use `set` instead of `Set`

Comment: BTW: I don't see `tbCapture` in code - maybe you mean `tbCapturedImage` ?

Comment: What is "PAGE 4.6"? Also, you don't need all that code to reproduce the problem. Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `self` and `set` instead of `Set`

And probably you should use `tbCapturedImage` instead of `tbCapture`

```
 def Capture(self): # self
     self.tbCapturedImage.set("test")  # self, set and tbCapturedImage
```

---

BTW: you can use `command=` in `Button` instead of `bind`

```
 self.btnCapture = Button(master, command=self.Capture)
```

or

```
 self.btnCapture.configure(command=self.Capture)
```

`command=` doesn't send `event` so method doesn't need argument `event`